# Constructing an inverse of a composite function

Tags: functions, inverse-function

Given:  $A,B,C\subset \mathbb R$ and two functions $f:A\to B \;\& \;g:B\to C$  defined by $$f(x) = 2x + 1\;\;\&\;\;g(x) = \frac x3$$ Prove $(g \circ  f)^{-1} = f^{-1} \circ g^{-1}$

I've proved that g is one-one and onto.

How do I proceed further?

Comment: This is a statement that holds for invertible functions in general and is very easy to prove, straight from the definitions.

Comment: Do we have $A=B=C=\mathbb R$ here?

Comment: I have reformatted your question...please check to make sure I didn't change your meaning.  You never said what the sets $A,B,C$ were; I guessed that they were subsets of the real numbers.

Comment: Hint:  can you explicitly write out the inverse functions $f^{-1},g^{-1},(f\circ g)^{-1}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first write :
$$
g \circ f(x) = g(f(x)) = \frac{2x+1}{3}
$$
Now we try to invert it :
$$
y = \frac{2x+1}{3} \implies 3y = 2x+1 \implies \frac{3y-1}{2} = x \implies (g \circ f)^{-1}(x) = \frac{3x-1}{2}
$$
Now we compute $f^{-1}$ and $g^{-1}$ :
$$
2x+1 = y \implies x = \frac{y-1}{2} \implies f^{-1}(x) = \frac{x-1}{2} \\
\frac{x}{3} = y \implies x = 3y \implies g^{-1}(x) = 3x
$$
Finally we check the statement :
$$
f^{-1} \circ g^{-1}(x) = \frac{3x-1}{2} = (g \circ f)^{-1}(x)
$$

Answer (score 1):

Answer by Zubzub calculates the functions and checks the identity explicitly for the given functions, which is probably what is expected. Here I give abstract reasoning why this always must hold which would be good exercise for you to try.

*Hint 1:* Can you define what invertible function is without mentioning bijectivity?

*Answer 1:*

> We say that $f\colon A\to B$ is invertible if there exists $g\colon B\to A$ such that $g\circ f = \operatorname{id}_A$ and $f\circ g = \operatorname{id}_B$. Such $g$ must be unique, so we write $g = f^{-1}$.

*Hint 2*: Using the above definition, could you prove that for invertible functions $f\colon A\to B$ and $g\colon B\to C$ inverse of the composition is given by $(g\circ f)^{-1} = f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}$?

*Answer 2:*

> $(g\circ f)\circ (f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}) = g\circ(f\circ f^{-1})\circ g^{-1} = g\circ \operatorname{id}_B\circ g^{-1} = g\circ g^{-1} =\operatorname{id}_C\\$ $(f^{-1}\circ g^{-1})\circ (g\circ f)= f^{-1}\circ(g^{-1}\circ g)\circ f = f^{-1}\circ \operatorname{id}_B\circ f = f^{-1}\circ f = \operatorname{id}_A\\$ $\implies(g\circ f)^{-1} = f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}$